Maven failed to build the jar file due to Java version mismatching
This issue was occurred when I tried to build jar file from my spring boot project. First I entered following command in my terminal:
./mvnw clean package

then I saw following log message:
/JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter$ ./mvnw clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----< com.jayathilakaRiceProducts:JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter >-----
[INFO] Building JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.3.2:clean (default-clean) @ JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/rashmika/Paid Projects/JayathilakaRiceProducts_With printer/PaysheetPrinter_JayathilakaRiceProducts/JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] Copying 2 resources from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 17 source files with javac [debug release 21] to target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.641 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-03T19:19:55+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 21 not supported -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
rashmika@rashmika-Aspire-A515-53G:~/Paid Projects/JayathilakaRiceProducts_With printer/PaysheetPrinter_JayathilakaRiceProducts/JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter$ ./mvnw clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----< com.jayathilakaRiceProducts:JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter >-----
[INFO] Building JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.3.2:clean (default-clean) @ JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/rashmika/Paid Projects/JayathilakaRiceProducts_With printer/PaysheetPrinter_JayathilakaRiceProducts/JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] Copying 2 resources from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 17 source files with javac [debug release 21] to target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.231 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-03T19:20:44+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 21 not supported -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException


my pom.xml file is this.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jayathilakaRiceProducts</groupId>
    <artifactId>JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JayathilakaPosBackedWithPrinter</name>
    <description>jayathilaka pos backend with printer</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jpos/jpos -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>



<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>7.1.12</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>5.5.13.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->


<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.print</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>javax.print-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.usb4java</groupId>
            <artifactId>usb4java-javax</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.usb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>javax-usb-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.0.2</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


I can see this is because of some kind of Java version mismatching. but my system Java version matches with the pom.xml

What is the content of the JAVA_HOME variable? What Java installation does it point to? What's the output of $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version (or javac -version if you don't have a JAVA_HOME specified)

Just post the output of mvn --version here... (in your question)

I figured it out. I had to point Maven to use Java 21. For some reason Maven still use Java 17 which was my first java installation version.
These are the steps i followed. (My OS is Ubuntu 22)

Open the terminal in spring boot project.
enter following code to check the system java version

$ java --version
openjdk 21.0.4 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04, mixed mode, sharing)


run following command to check the maven java version

$ ./mvnw -v
Apache Maven 3.9.7 (8b094c9513efc1b9ce2d952b3b9c8eaedaf8cbf0)
Maven home: /home/rashmika/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.9.7/2a4cb831
Java version: 17.0.6, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.8.0-47-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

As you can see here, I got two different java versions for maven and system.
to solve the issue, we need to bring those two java versions to one.
this is how we can do that.

find the java installed location.

sudo update-alternatives --config java

this is my output for that command
  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   2111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin/java          1091      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   2111      manual mode


from here, i need only /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64 part.
2.set the $JAVA_HOME variable
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64

3.confirm the changes
echo $JAVA_HOME

4.now problem should be solved. we can build the jar file
./mvnw clean package

